# Can you better define a file:/// URL pattern for host permissions in the Chrome extension manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Google Chrome extension currently has the following permissions in the manifest;

```
"permissions": [
   "nativeMessaging",
   "downloads",
   "activeTab",
   "notifications",
   "storage",
   "contextMenus,
   "file://*/*"
 ]
```

I would like to more specifically define the file:/// as Google Chrome shows that the extension has full access to all files on the Windows client.

Ultimately I only need access to the users Temp directory that is C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp so I have tried the following in the manifest

```
"file:///%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Temp/*"
```

I do not get any errors and the extension has access to the temp folder but Google Chrome still shows that the extension has access to file:///*.

In the interests of only asking for the permissions needed is it possible to define a more exact path?  Further is something like a path to the Temp folder which is user name dependent (for windows) possible?

Comment: No, you can't, `file:` scheme doesn't have a concept of domains/origins.

Comment: Try registering your extension for Native File System API origin trials, [link](https://web.dev/native-file-system/#origin-trial).

Comment: Thanks.  I will leave my permissions as they are for file.